# pausing a batch file while waiting for java to finish

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I need to run a two java programs from a batch script. I need to wait for the first java program to finish running before the second one starts. Is there a way to do this? I'm on a windows machine and I can't edit the java programs so I'm using a batch script to launch them.

So it would be something like this

```
cd %PARSEDIR%
set CLASSPATH=.\lib\jpcap-0.01.16.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.\lib\jpcap.jar
START /WAIT java -Xms768m -Xmx768m -classpath %CLASSPATH% parser.test.firstStage %2
timeout 5
START /WAIT java -Xms768m -Xmx768m -classpath %CLASSPATH% parser.test.lastStage %2
```

I need the first program to finish before the the batch script moves on. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks!

edit: added what the code currently looks like

Comment: It would be ugly, but you could have the whole thing as a java program, which calls both main() methods of other classes and commands from the operating system.

Comment: There are some other stuff that needs to be done in bat that I don't want to recode into java but it may come to that if I can't get this to work

Answer (score 3):

Use the `start /WAIT` command (http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: I'm using the start /wait command but something's not really working correctly, it just starts then closes the java process.

Comment: @Jack when you run your Java process as _standalone_ does it also closed right away ? please also share your batch file

Comment: When I run the java process standalone it works fine. I have two separate batch files that run each process standalone and those batch files work fine.

Comment: @Jack make sure to add title to your command , I mean something like start "foo" /WAIT c:\temp\yours.bat

Comment: start /wait worked. It was failing because I had an extra layer of quotes and it was throwing off the java program. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jack please consider upvote or accept this answer if it was helpful for you